# Math analysis proof.

Tags: analysis

Prove: If M is a finite point set, then M has a right-most point and a left-most point.

So far I know that the statement that the point set M is FINITE means that there is a positive integer n such that M contains n points but M does not contain n+1 points.
Also the statement that the point set M is INFINITE means that M is not finite.

However, I am stuck on proving this formally.

Comment: What is $M$ a subset of?  $\Bbb R$?  Some arbitrary ordered set?

Comment: Try with induction.  Then notice that a size $n+1$ pointset is a size $n$ pointset unioned with a size $1$ pointset.  The furthest right is either going to be among the original $n$ or it will be the new $n+1$'st element.

Answer (score 1):

It seems we are told to prove the following

**Theorem.** Any nonempty finite ordered set has a maximal element.

*Proof.* Let $M$ be such a set. Then there is an $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ and a bijection $\phi: \>[n]\to M$. We say that $|M|=n$ in this case.

If $n=1$ then the unique $a\in M$ is trivially the maximal element of $M$.

Assume that the claim is true for all sets $X$ with $|X|=n$, and consider an $M$ with $|M|=n+1$. Choose a bijective $\phi:\>[n+1]\to M$, and let $\phi(n+1)=a$. The set $M':=M\setminus\{a\}$ has $n$ elements, hence a maximal element $b$ by the induction hypothesis. Since $b\ne a$ by construction we either have $b<a$ or $b>a$. The transitivity of $<$ then implies that in the first case $a$ is the maximal element of $M$, and in the second case $b$.$\qquad\square$